# How to fix autocomplete into two databases that appear with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, autocomplete

I made an autocomplete with Codeigniter, but the data that appears is only one data such as the example I searched for data: `1011 ...`, the data that appears is only numeric, whereas I want to display two data at once when doing a search with autocomplete to fill my form, so I want my autocomplete to display two data like `'10116198 - Farrid'` not just one data like this `'10116198'` only.

I have tried to add rows but still, the data appears only one data does not even show the data at all for this autocomplete

this is my controller >

```
function get_autocomplete()
{
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $result = $this->Data_model->search_data($_GET['term']);
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            foreach ($result as $row)
                $arr_result[] = array(
                    'label'            => $row->nip,'-',nama,
                );
            echo json_encode($arr_result);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my model >

```
function search_data($title)
{
    $this->db->like('nip', $title, 'both');
    $this->db->order_by('nip', 'ASC');
    $this->db->limit(10);
    return $this->db->get('pegawai')->result();
}
```

this is my view >

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h6 class="m-1 font-weight-bold text-dark">Pengguna Kuasa/Anggaran</h6>
    <input type="text" name="nip" id="nip" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my footer >

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#nip').autocomplete({
            source: "<?php echo site_url('data/get_autocomplete'); ?>",
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('[name="nip"]').val(ui.item.label);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

I expect output in autocomplete is `'10116198 - Farrid'` and NOT expect `'1011619'` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the result of your data using `.` (dot), not using a comma, your array should be like this :

```
function get_autocomplete()
{
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $result = $this->Data_model->search_data($_GET['term']);
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            foreach ($result as $row)
                $arr_result[] = array(
                    'label'            => $row->nip . ' - ' . $row->nama,
                );
            echo json_encode($arr_result);
        }
    }
}
```